# need some help understanding an aspect of this code

Tags: java

Please refer the code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String words = "";
    String output = "";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        words = scan.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
            output += words.charAt(words.length() - i - 1);
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
    System.out.print(output);


 }
}
```

First of all, sorry for the vague title but I didn't know how to put it any other way. I am new to Java and for uni, we were given a task that read standard input until the end of file and then outputs the reverse of each line.

I was wondering how

```
String output
```

is able to output multiple strings at the end. Shouldn't it only be able to hold one string? Sorry if this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: One String can contain many lines. Each line is separated by your platform-dependent line separator, usually either just a newline ("\n") or a carriage return plus a newline ("\r\n").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One single string can hold a sequence of characters. You may not know this, but a "new line" is also a character. This means that the following can be stored in a single string:

```
Hello World
Bye World
```

It's just a string with the characters "Hello World", followed by a new line character, followed by "Bye World".

In Java, the new line character is denoted by `\n`.

In the code, you start with an empty string:

```
String output = "";
```

Then in the loop, you start appending characters in reverse order to it:

```
output += words.charAt(words.length() - i - 1);
```

Just before the end of the iteration of the while loop, you add a new line to the output:

```
output += "\n";
```

Comment: Ah thank you that makes a lot of sense. Didn't expect such a negative response from anyone else but this clears everything up. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`output` does not hold more than one string. A string can have multiple lines as denoted by the `\n` in your code. When you print `\n`, you are printing a new line. This is still one string, just with multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Because
**String is an immutable class in Java**. An immutable class is simply a class whose instances cannot be modified. All information in an instance is initialized when the instance is created and the information can not be modified.

```
public class ExampleString{

public static void main(String[] args) {

   String examp="";
   examp="HI";
   examp=examp+"HOW";
   System.out.println(examp);




 }
}
```

output: HIHOW